# Cant use class defined inside lib folder in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, load

I have created a class in my lib folder inside my rails app lib/pundit/current_context.rb :

```
class CurrentContext
  attr_reader :user, :account_asso

  def initialize(user, account_asso)
    @user = user
    @account_asso = account_asso
  end
end
```

This class is then called in my base_controller :

```
  def pundit_user
    CurrentContext.new(current_user, account_asso)
  end
```

I am always getting :

```
NameError - uninitialized constant Api::V1::BaseController::CurrentContext:
```

I thought it might be because I am not loading the files inside lib ?
so I added `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` inside my config/application.rb file :

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module QuickBedApi
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
  end

end
```

Unfortunately I am still getting the error. How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include all subdirectories of lib/ directory automatically,

`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Answer (score 0):

try include all the folders of `lib`:

```
config.autoload_paths.concat `find -type d`.split($/).map {|f| Rails.root.join(f) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to call a Module of my lib folder.

Even the "config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)" didn't work for me.

After some researchs I figured out that i had to put " require 'my_modules' "in addition of the " include MyModules " in my file to be able to call it.

so you can try to require it